# Delphi 32 components to emulate "Patient Journey Demonstrator"

Tags: delphi, user-interface, panel

Does anyone knows any components that mimic the resizable flow panel of the [Patient Journey Demonstrator](http://pjd.mscui.net/default.htm) presented for the Microsoft Health Common User Interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what functionalities you exactly need, check http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExLayoutControl/, for example. Anyway, controls using vector graphics can resize in a different way than those using bitmap graphics.

Comment: thanks, it´s a start. Sorry if i dont make myself clear. Just take a little time to watch the demo. I´m just amazed by the final result, and i was thinking: What i need to do to have a final result like that???

Comment: You need probably to take a hundred UI obsessed people and set them loose in Microsoft Expression Blend Designer for two weeks.